# Order by relationship's value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

If I have a table called `users`:

```
| id | username | password |
```

And a table called `user_stats`:

```
| id | user_id | num_posts |
```

How can I get all users and sort them by the number of posts they have?

My `User.php` model has this relationship:

```
public function stats()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\UserStat');
}
```

And my `UserStat.php` model has this relationship:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I know I can do a join using the query builder, like:

```
$users = User::join('user_stats', 'users.id', '=', user_stats.user_id')
    ->orderBy('user_stats.num_posts', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

But is there a better way to do it using just the Eloquent ORM?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd be able to handle this with just Eloquent but it can get you very close...  You could use methods on the `Collection` to get you the rest of the way.

```
$users = App\User::with('stats')->get();
$sortedUsers = $users->sortByDesc(function($user) {
    return $user->stats->count();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be

```
public function stats()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\UserStat')->orderBy('num_posts', 'desc');
}

$users = App\User::with('stats')->get();
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Short story:

1. Define a custom [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to make something like `$user->postCount` available.
2. Use this accessor in a `sortByDesc` callback function.

---

Long explanation:

1. Define this custom accessor in your `User` model.

   ```
   public function getPostCountAttribute() {
       $stats = $this->stats;  // from the 'stats()' you have defined
       return $stats->num_posts;
   }
   ```
2. Then, use the [sortByDesc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sortbydesc) to sort your collection. Remember to make sure the stats() relationship is eager-loaded in your `User` models when you use the `postCount`, otherwise Laravel will create 1 query for each `User` object in your collection.

   ```
   //  Eager Loading stats() relationship
   $users = User::with('stats')->get();

   //  Sort by descending using the postCount attribute of User
   $sorted = $users->sortByDesc(function ($user) {
       return $user->postCount;
   });
   ```